# how to setup odoo in visual studio 2019?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am currently a trainee as an odoo developer. There are multiple IDEs where we can use debug odoo like my team mates are doing. some on pycharm, some on eclipse and so on. I used to do development on Visual Studio code and run through Python interpreter.
But now, I want to switch to proper IDE. I have downloaded visual studio 2019 for this purpose.

My question is, how to create and edit debug configuration for odoo like we do in pycharm.
what I did is

1. created a new project of python application
2. right click on **solution > add > existing folder** and then selected whole odoo folder that I have downloaded from github
3. right click on **solution > properties** and in general tab, I gave path of 'odoo-bin' against 'startup file' and in debug tab, gave configuration of odoo i.e. 
   (`-r db_user -w db_password --addons-path=addons`).

I saved this thing, but when I click on start button <kbd>F5</kbd> it starts debugging but breaks on function in 'api.py' file.

The function I used is:

```
def __getitem__(self, model_name):
        """ Return an empty recordset from the given model. """
        return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
```

and the error shown is

> exception thrown (None,)